# Spring AMQP Outbound Adapter behavior when exchange not found

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-rabbit, spring-integration-amqp

I have a spring integration code that connects a JMS listener (that listens to a mq series local queue)

```
    <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter>
```

and forwards the message to a rabbitmq (not controlled by me) via a

```
    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

I am trying to keep this transactional meaning that if the rabbitmq did not receive the message I want to keep it in the MQ series local queue.
However I noticed that if the exchange that was mentioned in the rabbitmq configurations did not exist I see in my logs this line:

```
ERROR (CachingConnectionFactory.java:292)     - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'xxx' in vhost 'xxx', class-id=60, method-id=40)
```

But my message disappears for the mq series local queue.

What shall i do do make it retry to send the message if the rabbitmq broker fails or if the exchange does not exists?

Thanks for your help,
My configuration:

```
   <int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
        id="x.y.z" channel="channel-in"
        error-channel="errorChannel" header-mapper="jmsIntegrationHeaderMapper"
        acknowledge="transacted" destination-name="a.b.c" />

    <int:channel id="channel-in">

    </int:channel>

    <int:header-enricher input-channel="channel-in"
        output-channel="channel-out">
        <int:header name="url"
            expression="'amqp://${amqp.user}@${amqp.host}:${amqp.port}/${amqp.vhost}'"></int:header>
    </int:header-enricher>


    <int:channel id="channel-out">
    </int:channel>

    <int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter
        channel="channel-out" amqp-template="amqpTemplate"
        routing-key="crd" mapped-request-headers="*" exchange-name="${amqp.exchange}">
    </int-amqp:outbound-channel-adapter>


    <rabbit:connection-factory id="amqpConnectionFactory" addresses="${amqp.host}:${amqp.port}"
                           cache-mode="CONNECTION"
                           channel-cache-size="25"
                           username="${amqp.user}"
                           password="${amqp.pass}"
                           virtual-host="${amqp.vhost}"/>

    <rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate"
                 connection-factory="amqpConnectionFactory" mandatory="true" channel-transacted="true"/>
```

Comment: What version of Spring Integration are you using?

Comment: I am using spring integration 4.

Comment: You need to set `acknowledge=transcted` so that an exception will roll back the transaction; we changed the default to that in 4.2.

Comment: It was already set `<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
  id="adapter.jms.xxxx" channel="channel.direct.incoming-xxxx"
  error-channel="errorChannel" header-mapper="jmsIntegrationHeaderMapper"
  acknowledge="transacted" destination-name="xxxx" /> ` The strange this is that there is no exception only a line of error that I mentioned in the post.

Comment: I use a CachingConnectionFactor  `public void shutdownCompleted(ShutdownSignalException cause) {
  if (RabbitUtils.isPassiveDeclarationChannelClose(cause)) {
   if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
    logger.debug("Channel shutdown: " + cause.getMessage());
   }
  }
  else if (!RabbitUtils.isNormalChannelClose(cause)) {
   logger.error("Channel shutdown: " + cause.getMessage());
  }
 }`  the code only logs the error but does not raise an exception, maybe that's why?

Answer (score 0):

Unlike JMS, publishing to RabbitMQ is asynchronous (which is why it's generally faster), so the failure for a missing exchange is reported on a different thread; you can add a listener to get the notification instead of it just being logged.

You can enable transactions `template.setChannelTransacted(true);` and then the failure will be reported on the publishing thread because it will be blocked waiting for the reply from the `txCommit()` when the IO error occurs.

However, transactions are quite expensive so can hurt performance.

For other errors (e.g. exchange exists, but no route to a queue), you can use publisher confirms and returns but, again, waiting for a confirmation for each individual message published will slow down performance.

**EDIT**

You should get an exception on `txCommit`.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpIOException: java.io.IOException
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitUtils.commitIfNecessary(RabbitUtils.java:107) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doSend(RabbitTemplate.java:2003) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.lambda$send$3(RabbitTemplate.java:865) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1841) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1784) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.send(RabbitTemplate.java:864) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:927) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(RabbitTemplate.java:921) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.So47454769Application.lambda$0(So47454769Application.java:29) [classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot-2.0.0.M7.jar:2.0.0.M7]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: null
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:126) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.wrap(AMQChannel.java:122) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:144) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:1519) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.txCommit(ChannelN.java:52) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.txCommit(PublisherCallbackChannelImpl.java:588) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory$CachedChannelInvocationHandler.invoke(CachingConnectionFactory.java:981) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy60.txCommit(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.RabbitUtils.commitIfNecessary(RabbitUtils.java:104) ~[spring-rabbit-2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'junk' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.ValueOrException.getValue(ValueOrException.java:66) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:36) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:494) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:288) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:138) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no exchange 'junk' in vhost '/', class-id=60, method-id=40)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.asyncShutdown(ChannelN.java:504) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.processAsync(ChannelN.java:346) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleCompleteInboundCommand(AMQChannel.java:178) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.handleFrame(AMQChannel.java:111) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.readFrame(AMQConnection.java:643) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.access$300(AMQConnection.java:47) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:581) ~[amqp-client-5.0.0.jar:5.0.0]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: `<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate" connection-factory="rabbitConnectionFactory" channel-transacted="true" mandatory="true"  />`  I am already using the property channel-transacted, yet the error does not occur.

Comment: Perhaps you are not using that template in the outbound adapter - I added the stack trace you should see. Edit the question to show your complete configuration.

Comment: Just posted my configuration, the weird thing is that I am not at all having this exception.

Comment: OK i tried to put the exchange name in the  `<rabbit:template id="amqpTemplate"`  And now I have the exception and it rolled back to the JMS queue with the exception that you mentioned that's great. However if I need to retry automatically what should I use? Thanks,

Comment: It's not clear what you mean; when the message rolls back it will be redelivered by JMS (perhaps behind any prefetched messages).